# Dict comprehension with a dict subclass?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Is it possible (in Python 3.6+) to have or implement dict comprehensions on a dict subclass, with the result being an instance of that subclass instead of a normal dict? Something like `CustomDict{k: v for k, v in list_of_tuples}`?

Is there any way at all to customize list/dict comprehensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your subclass can consume an iterable of 2-tuples:

```
CustomDict((k, v) for k, v in list_of_tuples)
```

You can't use the language construct style `{...}` on your subclass, unless of course, you want to tweak some Python internals.

Comment: Thanks, that would work. I had never thought about a comprehension and its enclosing brackets as syntactically separate things, but it looks like [they are](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-lists-sets-and-dictionaries).